# Enlarge div using CSS and remove other divs under same parent when clicked

Tags: html, css, resize, jquery-animate

.animate on jQuery is causing me trouble, so I'd like to resize a div without it.

I'm looking to enlarge boxes using CSS. I have 4 boxes next to each other, when one of them is clicked, it should enlarge, while the rest of the boxes move out of the screen (potentially all those to the left go left, all those to the right go right). The boxes are in a rectangle that should enlarge as wel..

I think it can be done with making a new class in CSS (.thumb:click), but how do I use Javascript/HTML to execute the enlargement & push off screen?

HTML:

```
            <div class="portItem">
                     <div class="itemContent-wrap">
                          <div class="itemContent">
                              <div class="container">
                                  <div class="thumbWrap">
                                      <div class="thumb"></div>
                                      <div class="thumb"></div>
                                      <div class="thumb"></div>
                                      <div class="thumb"></div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                     </div> 
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.itemContent-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}



.itemContent {
  height: 250px;
  width: auto;
  position: static;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 1px 0px 20px black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left:-12.5%;
  margin-right:-12.5%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
    width: 110%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: transparent; 
    position: relative;
}

.thumbWrap {
  height: 220px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 2000px;

}

.thumb {
  height: 200px;
  width: 450px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #D0E182;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

//my guess...
.thumb:click {

}
```

Javascript (while using .animate... want to avoid this)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.thumb').click(function()
   {
      $('.itemContent').css("cursor","pointer");
      $('.itemContent').animate({height: "500px"}, 'slow');
      $(this).animate({width: "900px",height:"400px"}, 'slow');
   });

$('.thumb').mouseout(function()
  {   
      $('.itemContent').animate({height: "250px"}, 'slow');
      $(this).animate({width: "450px",height:"200px"}, 'slow');
   });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4GFb/

Thank you in advance!

Comment: One glaring problem I see with your code is a .click() function and a .mouseout() function...you should do .mouseleave() with .mouseenter(). They are both jQuery functions. .mouseout() is a vanilla Javascript event handler.

See: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing existing in CSS for :click behaviour. So you did it right with JS/HTML.
I would suggest this tuto about jQuery sliding left/right :

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Also I would add a .active class to help you to code a global function for all the divs

Hope this helps ?

Comment: But I'm looking to enlarge a div, not to slide it. I've used the sliding effects before but I don't see how they'd help me in this situation. I'll look into the .active class now. Thanks